# Finding the Prime Number using a WHILE LOOP (not a for loop)in php

Tags: php

So I am just starting to learn a PHP in college. I have been given a simple task of finding the prime numbers of 101 in PHP but using a while loop. I cant figure it out.It ahs to use a while loop rather a for loop, teacher specifications. Many thanks.
This is my pathetic code,(& this only prints out the numbers from 1 to 101, im ever new to it)

```
<?php
$x = 1; 
$maxNumber=101;
while($x <= $maxNumber) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
    $x++;
} 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

So, you would devide by 2. Check if the number turns into a decimal. If so it's prime.

You can use is_float. Also 2/2=1. Ignore 1.